# Azure automated KeyVault access

Tags: azure

I need to pull certificates from Keyvault when running Bash script.

At the moment, before running that script, I come a long journey - do 'az login' in console, then go to the deviceauth on the portal, enter the device code, confirm that it's really me by providing a code from auth app and after this script works fine. But this isn't automatic way.

How it's possible to make it fully automatic, without manual logging by a human? In fact, I don't need a full access, just read-only access to keyvault(s) so, may be, some kind of specially crafted token, which I can store locally, can help.

So, I will appreciate any keywords and/or links to documents and/or solutions I need to search/read/implement in order to get things done.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [Service Principal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) for an identity you can use in your script.
Once you have created the SP you can grant it access to your Key Vault, then in the script you can use the Az Login command with the service principal credentials as per this [doc.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal)

Answer (score 1):

See this tool:
https://github.com/herkit/getazurecert

Howto use:

```
keyvaultname="my-certificate-keyvault"
serviceprincipalname=sp-$(hostname)
az login # log in with your user
tenantId=$(az account show --query tenantId -o tsv)
app=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $serviceprincipalname --create-cert)
appId=$(echo $app | jq -r .appId)
certFile=$(echo $app | jq -r .fileWithCertAndPrivateKey)
objectId=$(az ad sp show --id $appId --query objectId -o tsv)
az keyvault set-policy --name $keyvaultname --object-id $objectId --secret-permission get --certificate-permission get
az login --service-principal -u http://$serviceprincipalname -p $certFile --tenant $tenantId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After migration to Graph API something changed and obtaining objectId need to be done by querying 'id' (not 'objectId') property. Please, give one more direction:

az login --service-principal -u http://sp-healthchk ... returns the following error:

Application with identifier 'http://sp-healthchk' was not found in the directory '...'. This can happen if the app has not been installed by the administrator of tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.

'az ad app permission admin-consent ...' stops with "Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden". What to read next? :-)

Comment: Verify if the sp-healthchk exists in your Azure Active Directory. You need to have proper privileged role to grand admin consent, probably it doesn't work because the sp doesn't exist.